# Route parametrs empty in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I try print router parametrs but req.params is empty, don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In app.js:

```
...
var shareFile=require('./controllers/file/share');
...
app.use('/share/:id', shareFile);
...
```

And share.js controller:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.params)
});

module.exports = router;
```

`localhost:3000/share/123` gives empty json page. Changing `res.send` to `console.log` gives `{}`.

Thanks

Comment: Put your router on `/share` instead of `/share/:id` and then change to `router.get('/:id', ...)`.  Then, you will have `req.params`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

req.params will produce `{id: 'abc'}` when the routing is defined as `/share/:id` and you made the call to `http://yourserver/share/abc`

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.params)
});
```

Above you should expect that req.params will be empty here because your are not expecting them.  But you should see them here:

```
router.get('/share/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.params)
});
```